# Neural Net use for finding specific types of websites?

Tags: java, neural-network

So I'm working on my first project and I'm trying to incorporate a neural net in it somehow. At the moment I just created web crawler that basically takes a word as input and then performs a google search and retrieves the html data of the links.

Now I am trying to only use the html data from specific types of websites, in my case websites that offer free educational content/courses. Example being This site https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-092-java-preparation-for-6-170-january-iap-2006/index.htm 
I'm new to neural nets but is this something a neural net is able to do or would another method be better?

Also the rest of my code, such as for web crawler is in Java, so If neural net is applicable in this case what library or tool would you guys recommend for building/training the neural net. I was thinking Neuroph but would love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: When you get an html content from a web page , what do you wanna predict exactly ? i mean , you take as input a link , what do you wanna get in output ?

Comment: You can check my suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Neural Networks , it's for predicting something , for example you get an image as input and as ouput you'll have to get the nature of the image , *for example knowing what's the content of image : is it a cat or a dog .. etc*

- **About Web Crawler :**

The web crawler you've been talking about is not something that necessarily needs neural network ( the idea that you wanted ) , but in case you wanna add some predictions then you can use it , *for example taking word as input , making google search about it and then predicting nature of content*

I dont know exacly what you wanna predict or the nature of prediction you want to do ( classification or regression ) but **i can suggest you first how to take an input html**

---

- **Taking Html content as input :**

First thing to mention , the neural networks doesnt treat caracters , it treats numbers , so if you wanna treat an html content you'll have to use a mecanism , and that's not an easy step , there is a domain called **NLP ( Natural Language Processing )** which gives you some good ways to treat texts , you can also use it for html content ( or in a different way if you want ).

I already made before a project of Text Suggestion with a recurrent neural network where i use one the NLP's methods , you can check it on my github because i explained on the *Readme* all the steps in details : https://github.com/KaramMed/Modele-de-Suggestion-du-Texte

- **About Library :**

I recommand you to use ***TensorFlow*** for Java , it's one of the best librairies of Deep Learning and you can find so much tutorials about it

Comment: What would you recommend for finding only free online courses/educational content. Im trying to have an input be a subject and experience level and then perform a search which finds 3 good free online courses and then download the html data to then combine the 3 sites course material to create a custom course that is a combination of the three sites. With neural nets I was thinking about using them to predict whether or not a website was a good online course I could download html data from, but Im not sure if this is practical so Im open to suggestions.

Comment: First , what you say of finding 3 free online courses , you should see from the machine's points of view ( how can only html content say if it's free or not ? ) maybe seeing if it contains the word "free" , it will look how many times the word " free " was mentionned and keep 3 with the most times ( just an idea but we can suggest better )
@DonC24

Comment: Secondly , predicting if the course is good or not , this is difficult but possible , you will need data , i mean that you will have to feed the network yourself , ( you give it the html of a course that you already know its good and you classify it as good , you give it another one bad and you classify it as bad ... etc ) but this will be kinda difficult because you will need so much data , you will have to find an automatic way  @DonC24

Comment: What i suggest you to do to get a dataset, is that you can do an online form ( for example with google forms ) and share it with your friends and other people , where they have to put a link of a course a say if its good or bad , in this way you will have a big dataset to use @DonC24

Comment: You will train your network with the dataset using an NLP method for the html content ( you can see my project's readme to get some ideas ) and after your network will be ready then you can give it a link , and he will predict if that new course given is bad or not with a certain accuracy @DonC24

Comment: Gotcha, in terms of whether it being free or not I wasn't actually planning on filtering for free courses but rather just use the neural net by feeding the net courses that fit my criteria, such as being free. Im guessing there is no way to really tell how much data I will need to feed it, and that I just keep feeding it data until I get to a acceptable level of error. But thank you for the info, you helped me see that I was thinking about neural nets all wrong, you've been super helpful

Comment: You're welcome , and if you ever need something about that im here @DonC24